# Merge columns of Data Tables

Tags: c#, datatable

I am reading a ".xml" file from which I will be creating a Data Table. The columns of the Data Table depends on the ".xml" file.
Below is the example.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf5eG.jpg)

As shown the example, data1, data2, data3... etc will be fetched from .xml file. Data(a,b,c,d,as,asd.. etc) is added with respect to Column headers(item1,item2,item3... etc).

I want to merge columns with respect to content of a row. i.e. data1 of first column(item1) should be merged with data1 of 4th column(item4) and 4th column should be deleted. Is it possible?

Below is the expected output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmEwu.jpg)

Comment: Will you elaborate more?

Comment: @user6002727 I want to merge columns if the content of first row are same.

Comment: but there is no **asd** in first column? so how you can give in expected output?

Comment: @user6002727  expected output is after merging first and fourth column

Comment: **Huu Thien Tan Nguyen** has answer your question then, if not working then let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do this:

```
static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Item1", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Item2", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Item3", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Item4", typeof(string));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add("a", "as", "asd", "");
        table.Rows.Add("b", "asd", "asd", "");
        table.Rows.Add("c", "a", "asd", "");
        table.Rows.Add("d", "a", "asd", "");
        table.Rows.Add("", "", "", "a");
        table.Rows.Add("", "", "", "d");
        table.Rows.Add("", "", "", "asd");
        return table;
    }

    DataTable dt = GetTable();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Item4"].ToString()) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Item1"].ToString()))
        {
            dr["Item1"] = dr["Item4"].ToString(); //assign value of column 4 to column1 
        }
    }
    dt.Columns.Remove("Item4"); //delete column 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public DataTable CombileDataTable(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
    {
        DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
        {
            dtNew.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        }
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)
        {
            dtNew.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow item = dtNew.NewRow();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
            {
                item[col.ColumnName] = dt1.Rows[i][col.ColumnName];
            }
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)
            {
                item[col.ColumnName] = dt2.Rows[i][col.ColumnName];
            }
            dtNew.Rows.Add(item);
            dtNew.AcceptChanges();              
        }       
        return dtNew;
    }
```